# Disable certain modules with custom theme

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, theme

I have a custom theme that doesn't support rating, review or poll. How to disable those modules when I activate this theme. Is there a way?

Comment: Is this the only store installed? Or are there multiple themes or stores which *do* need these features?

Comment: I have more than two languages, but same domain, same theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is creating blank layout XML files for these functionalities in the theme's directory.

Go to `app/design/frontend/[theme_parent]/[theme_child]/layouts/`

Create the following files in this directory, leaving them *completely empty*: **review.xml** and **poll.xml**

These should remove the blocks for these functionalities for this specific theme.

Be sure to clear your Magento cache after making these changes.